# Почему в разных источниках разные запятые в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

*Ему казалось, что нервов у него не хватит(,) и он один поползет к балке.*

Наткнулся на это предложение на сайтах с вопросами по русскому языку. Начал гуглить источник (предложение обычно было связано с тестированием и диктантами учебных заведений) и обнаружил, что в некоторых учебных материалах этой запятой нет. Я считаю, что запятая здесь нужна (подразумеваю, что это сложное предложение).

В том числе хочу задать тот же вопрос в отношении предложения, которое придумал сейчас: *"Ей хватило времени для поездки(,) и она отправилась домой".*

Здесь корректно стоит запятая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вижу оснований в **первом случае** ставить запятую. Мы здесь имеем однородное подчинение придаточных:

> Ему казалось *{главная часть}*,
>
> что нервов у него не хватит *{первое придаточное}*
>
> и
>
> [что] он один поползет к балке *{второе придаточное}*.

Оба придаточных относятся к сказуемому в главной части — *казалось*.

Аналогичная конструкция из классики: *Но тут он вспомнил, что к нему должен прийти по делу толстовец Выволочнов и ему нельзя отлучаться* (Б. Пастернак. «Доктор Живаго»).

Во **втором случае** запятая стоит совершенно правильно, потому что это два простых предложения, не имеющие общего элемента.

Comment: Согласна с Вами, только подчинение здесь не параллельное, а однородное.

Comment: @Nektoid Вот как, спасибо большое. Забавно, что даже некоторые из преподавателей в своих ответах на сайтах поставили в первом варианте запятую. В том числе запятая стоит в практикуме по русскому языку по теме "Односоставные предложения" (8 класс).

Comment: @Екатерина действительно, ошибся. Спасибо, исправил ответ.